# AJAX POST not getting through to PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax

At the moment I have multiple forms, and am writing the JavaScript out very simply. I want to create a simple comment system using the following AJAX, but am running into troubles that I cannot sort out..

The AJAX call looks like this:

```
var dataString = 'commentauthor=' + commentauthor + '&parentid=' + parentid +'&linkid='+  
linkid + '&comment=' + comment + '&location=' + location;
alert("check : " + dataString)


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comments/addcomment.php",
    datatype: "html",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
        alert('comment added!');
    },
    error: function(){
    alert('failed adding comment!' +dataString);
    }
```

The dataString at all times pulls out the correct information from the forms. Also, the PHP the AJAX is sending it to already works when it's set as the forms action, and all the $_POST[''] names match up.

I've been looking around but can't figure it out. Am I encoding the data wrong or something? The PHP side of things doesn't even get to the AJAX response, so it's got to be just failing to send right?

Also, is there a better way to check JavaScript errors? I've been using the google chrome console but half the time when something goes wrong it doesn't through up an error anyway (like this time)

Comment: Can you use Chrome developer tools or Firebug in Firefox and check that the request is being sent and in what form the URL is ?

Comment: Quick check would be to use a var_dump in the php and see what you're sending via AJAX . . . data is likely not matching what you're expecting . . .

Comment: No, I'm looking at it now and embarrassingly there's not even a mention of the addcomment.php page in the network pages list. I've been changing the link to it, but surely it should at least show that the page retrieval failed?

Comment: It you're not seeing a request, the method might never be getting called, and thus no failure is happening . . .

Answer (score 0):

Is addcomment.php printing anything out?  I vaguely remember having a similar problem which was because the PHP file wasn't returning anything.  If it isn't, try this before the end of the file:

```
echo 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the problem for me, thanks for answering though